# Abnormal client call while trying to delete PostgreSQL database?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

[???????](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sY3Co.png)

I'm at my wit's end regarding this. I followed the instructions on how to drop a PostgreSQL database here: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-drop-database/

Yet now I am getting this error. Can someone please help me resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems.

First, you're killing your own connection.

Since you're connecting to `test` (line 8), when you kill all connections attached to `test` (line 13), you're killing your own connection. That's what's causing your actual error ("failed server connection").

Second, if you get past that, you're trying to drop a database that you're connected to -- that won't work.

You can get around both of these problems by connecting to a different database in the same cluster, specifically for the database and connection functions. For example, if you connect to the `postgres` database instead of `test`, then line 13 won't kill your own connection, and you'll be able to drop the database successfully. However, you'll want a connection to `test` itself for lines 27 and beyond, where you're creating tables in the `test` database.